# Create table and upload data in Teradata

Tags: sql, teradata

I am trying to upload 3,000 records to a Teradata table and I am getting the following error:

> Error reading import file at record 1: Index and length must refer to
>   a location within the string

I am importing the data with a txt file  and loading it with the following code:

```
-- Create Table
CT mytable
( col1 VARBYTE (35))

-- Insert data
INSERT INTO mytable VALUES(?)
```

The text file looks something like this

```
812619
816625
2B01112
...
```

Comment: Why is your column defined as varbyte?

Comment: That error is a .net error, correct? This seems like maybe it's a .net issue?

Comment: How are you loading the data? I am able to load the sample data in shared structure successfully.

Comment: @Aknapp, what teradata utility you are using?